# Does a martingale difference sequence $X_{t,i}$ imply $E[(\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^{M}X_{t,i})^2|\mathcal{F}_t]\leq C\times \frac{1}{M}$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingale

Let $X_{t,i}$ denote a martingale difference sequence in the $i$th time at day $t$, where $i=1,\cdots,M$. If $X_{t,i}$ is independent for $i=1,\cdots,M$, the result is straightforward. And I know that the martingale sequences are slightly weaker than independence. So does $E[(\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^{M}X_{t,i})^2|\mathcal{F}_t]\leq C\times \frac{1}{M}$ hold for all martingale difference sequences $X_{t,i}$, where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the information set at the begining of day $t$, and $C$ is a contant and $C>0$?

Comment: What is $C$ (you are missing either a description or a quantifier) and how might $t$ be related to $M,$ if at all?

Comment: @whuber $C$ is a constant and $C>0$. $M$ is the total number of observations at day $t$.